# Not getting all subdirs with searchoption.alldirectories

Tags: vb.net

I have several directories on disk that are all subdirectories of the same root.  They all follow the naming convention "topdir\subdir1\subdir2".  I want to enumerate all those subdirectories.  My code is:

```
    Dim dirs = From folder In Directory.EnumerateDirectories(topdir, "*", SearchOption.alldirectories)
    For Each folder In dirs
        ListBox1.Items.Add(folder)
    Next
```

When I run the code, I get a listbox that includes all topdir\subdir1 directories but no entiries for subdir2's.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
for each folder in new system.io.directoryinfo(topdirpath).EnumerateDirectories("*", SearchOption.alldirectories)

Next
```

My quess is that (topdir, "*", SearchOption.alldirectories) is not the right syntax.